# Janela modal não funciona corretamente ao clicar em YES

Tags: jquery

Estou a ter algma dificuldade com o seguinte código Jquery:

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#modalLogout').click(function(){
          $('#yes').click(function(){

              function time()
              {
                 $(location).attr('href',"destroy.php");
              }

              /*set 1s after ckick in yes, after that redirect to index*/           
              setTimeout(function(){time()},1000);
              /*table fadeout effect*/  
              $(".row").hide("slow");
        }); 
     });
});
```

O que se passa é que ao abrir uma janela modal de confirmação se tem a certeza se quer continuar ou terminar a sessão, quando eu clico em YES ele não faz nada na primeira vez, eu tenho de abrir de novo a janela e clicar em YES para a funcão time() ser executada. Já quando clico em NO funciona corretamente, ou seja fecha a janela e permanece na sessão iniciada. Como poderia alterar este estranho comportamento e melhorar o código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você só define o que precisa ser feito no click do YES quando clicar no `#modalLogout`. Não entendi bem a intenção dessa parte "de fora" do código, pelo visto bastaria definir o click do YES separadamente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#yes').click(function(){

          function time()
          {
             $(location).attr('href',"destroy.php");
          }

          /*set 1s after ckick in yes, after that redirect to index*/           
          setTimeout(time, 1000);
          /*table fadeout effect*/  
          $(".row").hide("slow");
    }); 
});
```

Repare que também simplifiquei sua chamada ao `setTimeout`.

Comment: Resolveu o problema, agora o comportamento é o correto!

Answer (score 1):

Se sua intenção era atribuir o evento click para o elemento `#yes` filho do elemento `#modalLogout` então a alteração que deve ser feita no seu código é a seguinte:

```
function time() {
    $(location).attr('href',"destroy.php");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#modalLogout #yes').click(function(){         
        setTimeout(time, 1000);

        $(".row").hide("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: O código de cima funcionou como eu queria, mas o seu vai mais de encontro ao que eu estava a programar e funciona também.